# Google Analytics and GTM Site search with URL query after # not?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Need help on figuring out a way to track my site search where the query string comes out of # instead of a ?. The problem I see currently is that Google Analytics does not recognize the query string after the # so it only gets the www.ywensite.com/Search but not the string after.
Any suggestions or recomendation?

Answer (score 1):

You have to append that part on the URL by rebuilding it before sending hit. This is not the querystring but the **fragment**, there is a dedicated variabile in the GTM.